# Enter adb shell from python

Tags: android, python, shell, adb

I'm trying to execute command to adb shell from python
I'm using Windows OS

On CMD :

```
C:\Users\deounix>adb shell
shell@android:/ $ su root
su root
root@android:/ # reboot
```

What I'm doing is :

```
import os

os.popen("adb shell & su root & reboot")
```

But it isn't work

How can I do it?

Comment: I did this in the past, I do not remember how I did it, but I remember there is a way to start the second process and later on to send to it input data and catch its output.

Comment: @MihaiHangiu How can I do this ?

Comment: use `subprocess` instead. also `adb reboot` without `shell` does not require root: `subprocess.check_output(['adb', 'reboot'])`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
import os
os.system("adb shell su -c reboot")
```

Comment: no it can't be like this, because it's do first command : adb shell
then it isn't do : su root inside adb shell

Comment: Call: adb shell; su root; reboot 
instead

Comment: Ah, right. Need the path. No matter. Updated answer with a command that works.

Answer (score -1):

```
import os
os.system("c:/platform-tools/adb devices")
```

To run any command like adb devices on python execute the above command
This will work definitely. You just need to confirm the path where you have got the adb shell